# ReactiveUI & Xamarin Forms: How to forward whenActived from Page to child views

Tags: reactiveui

I have a ReactiveContentPage with several ReactiveChildViews. One Problem that I still not solved satisfying is how to forward the whenActivated event to my child views as Xamarin Forms Views do not support an OnAppearing event that is neessary for .whenActivated to work.